# Update manager works but shows I'm not updating

Tags: 12.04, update-manager, bug-reporting

I'm using 12.04 (I cannot upgrade due to hardware issues). When an update comes in, it comes up and I update; however, it still says I've not updated in awhile. this is more of a nuasian, then an interference. Why doesn't Update manager see the last time I've updated? Why do I have to see that alert saying I need to run it? Even the system alerts are shows urgent messages to update after just a few minutes after updating. I have no other issues by this. Now it says 45 days, but it was saying over 500 days. but as you can see in the image below there are no updates to install as I just installed them.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's complaining because you haven't installed the [Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL).  That's the line that says "New important security and hardware support update" and has its own button  `More Info`.

The importance of this is described at the link, but briefly:

> Starting Aug 8, 2014 systems running 12.04.2 HWE, 12.04.3 HWE, or
>   12.04.4 HWE will no longer receive software updates for the kernel and, if you're running it, the graphics stack.